# Api Platform Pagination json format

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

i need help with the api platform pagination in json format.

here is my api_platform.yaml

```
api_platform:
    allow_plain_identifiers: true
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    formats:
        json:     ['application/json']
```

when i used the format hydra (default) i got something like this

```
"hydra:view": {
    "@id": "/api/galleries?page=1",
    "@type": "hydra:PartialCollectionView",
    "hydra:first": "/api/galleries?page=1",
    "hydra:last": "/api/galleries?page=6",
    "hydra:next": "/api/galleries?page=2"
  }
```

can anyone help me? if it's possible to get something like that in json format or another way to aply pagination with api  platform or symfony

thank you

Comment: There is no such thing on ApiPlatform by default for the json format. You have to code it on your own by decorating the serializer of the response.

Comment: '@id' & '@type' etc. its a thing that comes with 'application/ld+json' and this is the way you can use this. Its still valid json with hypermedia context information.

Comment: Since 2.2 apip includes \ApiPlatform\Core\JsonApi\Serializer\CollectionNormalizer. Maybe it will be activated by formats: jsonapi: ['application/vnd.api+json'].

Answer (score 4):

You shoud create an event Subscriber :

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Paginator;

final class PaginateJsonSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['normalizePagination', EventPriorities::PRE_RESPOND],
        ];
    }

    public function normalizePagination(
        ViewEvent $event
    ): void {
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

        if ($method !== Request::METHOD_GET) {
            return;
        }

        if (($data = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('data')) && $data instanceof Paginator) {
            $json = json_decode($event->getControllerResult(), true);
            $pagination = [
                'first' => 1,
                'current' => $data->getCurrentPage(),
                'last' => $data->getLastPage(),
                'previous' => $data->getCurrentPage() - 1 <= 0 ? 1 : $data->getCurrentPage() - 1,
                'next' => $data->getCurrentPage() + 1 > $data->getLastPage() ? $data->getLastPage() : $data->getCurrentPage() + 1,
                'totalItems' => $data->getTotalItems(),
                'parPage' => count($data)
            ];
            $res = [
                "data" => $json,
                "pagination" => $pagination
            ];
            $event->setControllerResult(json_encode($res));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In API Platform we have the `jsonapi` format which provides us the support for pagination. You can set the default config for number of records per page in api platform as:

```
# api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    defaults:
        pagination_items_per_page: 30 # Default value
    formats:
        jsonapi:  ['application/vnd.api+json']
```

With this configuration you would require to either have an item and collection normalizer to customise the structure of the response with pagination metadata OR you can use state providers for this purpose ([check here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/state-providers/))

You would still get all the necessary pagination metadata if you just leave your default format as `jsonapi`

This is the very good resource to read more about [API Platform pagination](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/)

Comment: Remember that you can set the format on entity level as well if you don't want to make it as the default

Comment: amazing!! thanks!!